# difference between gradle plugin android-library and AndroidStudio default com.android.library

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

In every example I've seeing floating around the internet, they say to build an android library, I should apply the android-library plugin. When I use the AndroidStudio IDE wizard to set up a library, it applies the com.android.library plugin instead. Are these the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the same thing. The fully-qualified form is replacing the old style, which is deprecated. This will become important in the future because Gradleware is planning on implementing a global plugin repository to replace the need to specify repositories in a `buildscript` tag, and using fully-qualified names will help properly locate plugins in that repository.